# Group and count identical rows in a 2d array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, grouping, counting

I am trying the group display values in a php array with how many times was duplicated in it.

Example:

```
[
    [6],
    [6],
    [6],
    [5,1],
    [3,3],
    [3,3],
    [3,2,1]
]
```

What I need as a result is the group of array and the count of them like this:

```
[[6],3],
[[5,1],1],
[[3,3],2],
[[3,2,1],1],
```

any type ?

***EDIT***

I tried to do it with this statement:

```
$result = array();
foreach ($myarray as $element) {
    $result[$element[0]][] = $element;
}
```

but I get the result as this:

`{"6":[[6],[6],[6]],"5":[[5,1]],"3":[[3,3],[3,3],[3,2,1]]}`

The problem is on the `3` group, I need to group [3,3] and [3,2,1] separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to to do what you have asked.

```
<?php
    //This is your array of elements
    $array = [[6],[6],[6],[5,1],[3,3],[3,3],[3,2,1]];

    //This is a list of items that the program knows about, and their position
    $known_items = array();

    //For all the elements
    foreach($array as $item){
        //Sort the array to be in ascending order so that any combination will work
        asort($item);

        //We only want the item array to have values, and not keys
        $item = array_values( $item );

        //Make the content of this item a string so we can use it as a key in arrays
        $arrString = json_encode( $item );

        //Have we seen this item before?
        if( array_key_exists( $arrString , $known_items ) ){
            //Yes we have, increase the count
            $known_items[ $arrString ][1]++;
        } else {
            //No we haven't. Add it and start the count as 1
            $known_items[ $arrString ] = [ $item, 1 ];
        }

    }

    echo json_encode( array_values( $known_items), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Comment: i did this ( more complex way , thanks for the comments too)
but maybe will not work if we make an array like [3,2,1] , [3,1,2] [2,3,1] 
in this situation we need to sort the arrays befor to make them as json.

Comment: @MoxGeek I have made changes to my answer. The array is now sorted, this will work for any combination.

Comment: yes , resort is perfect for my case , but it's doing the think perfectly thank you 

but why i'am feeling like we can optimise this algorithm more 
Becouse i will work with thousand and thousand of numbers

Comment: Thanks for marking this as the accepted answer. Probably, some optimisation can be done, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

This can be simply done without any sorting using the json_encode to create keys and the null coalescing operator to safely assist with incrementing the count.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/U5hBg))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $row) {
    $key = json_encode($row);
    $result[$key] = [$row, ($result[$key][1] ?? 0) + 1];
}
echo json_encode(array_values($result));
```

---

If you need to accommodate rows where the values may be in any order to qualify for their respective group, just call `sort()` before generating the grouping key.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/01usd))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $row) {
    sort($row);
    $key = json_encode($row);
    $result[$key] = [$row, ($result[$key][1] ?? 0) + 1];
}
echo json_encode(array_values($result));
```