# Remove duplicate rows from array even if their element ordering is different

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, duplicates

in PHP how to get this unique of array ?

```
$originalArray = [[2,48],[48,2],[19,31],[31,19]];
```

I want to get

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 48
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 19
            [1] => 31
        )

)
```

I tried with array_unique($array,SORT_REGULAR) but still won't work.
Is there other function to achieve this ?

Comment: No, there's no single other function to achieve this. You have to use several. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Use array_filter and provide custom function to check if array element should be removed or kept. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Comment: I see why you may use the word unique but as `[2,48]` is not == to `[48,2]` then that would explain why you will have to write some actual code to apply the test the makes those 2 different array be considered the same

Comment: Yes you're right i should not use word "Unique" @RiggsFolly the last comment give me solution. thanks all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similiar to [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74146002/2943403).  Use sorted, stringified keys to build the filtered result.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/n4HXYL))

```
$array = [[2,48],[48,2],[19,31],[31,19]];

$result = [];
foreach ($array as $row) {
    sort($row);
    $result[json_encode($row)] ??= $row;  // just = will also work
}
var_export(array_values($result));
```